# Using a variant array in a Workday function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to create an array of holidays to be used in a Workday function. When I run the code and get to the workday function I get a

> "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the WorkDay prperty of the WorksheetFunction class"

Can you help me with a solution? I'd would like the code to automaticly add any new holidays I add to the list.

Main control code

```
Public reqDate As Date
Public reqDateString As String
Public reqPurp As String
Public slaveFound As String
Public masterFound As String
Public lastrowSlave As String
Public lastrowMaster As String
Sub MainUpdate()

    Dim holidays As Variant
    Dim slaveDir As String
    Dim masterDir As String

    holidays = FindHolidays
    slaveDir = FindSlaveDir
    masterDir = FindMasterDir

    OpenWorkDir slaveDir, masterDir

    Select Case reqPurp
        Case Is = "CSL"
            PrepareSlaveCSL slaveDir, holidays
            CopySlaveMasterCSL slaveDir, masterDir
        Case Is = "OB"
            PrepareSlaveOB slaveDir, holidays
            CopySlaveMasterOB slaveDir, masterDir
    End Select

End Sub
```

Code for creating array:

```
Function FindHolidays() As Variant

    Dim dirHoli As String
    Dim lastrowHoli As Integer
    Dim arrayHoli As Variant
    Dim wbHoli As String

    dirHoli = "\\dklesv701.nilemah.com\common\Diverse\CustomerSatisfactionTeam\JUMP_R2P\8. Repporting\6. CSL2\Helligdage.xlsx"
    wbHoli = "Helligdage.xlsx"

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=dirHoli, UpdateLinks:=False
        Workbooks(wbHoli).Activate

    lastrowHoli = Workbooks(wbHoli).Sheets("Ark1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Workbooks(wbHoli).Sheets("Ark1").Range("B1").Formula = "=Year(Today())"

    ReDim arrayHoli(1 To lastrowHoli) As Variant
        For i = 1 To lastrowHoli
            If IsDate(Workbooks(wbHoli).Sheets("Ark1").Cells(i, 2)) Then
                arrayHoli(i) = Workbooks(wbHoli).Sheets("Ark1").Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        Next i

    FindHolidays = arrayHoli

    Workbooks(wbHoli).Close SaveChanges:=True

End Function
```

Code where I use the workday function:

```
Sub PrepareSlaveCSL(slaveDir As String, holidays As Variant)

    Dim MB5B As String
    Dim MB5Bdate As Date

    MsgBox Join(holidays)

    MB5Bdate = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(reqDate, -3, holidays)
```

Comment: Does `holidays` contain anything other than the holiday dates... seems like it might have some elements that are empty.

Comment: There's a heading, which it skips with ```IsDate```, but I guess that means the first entry is empty. I'm not sure how to do the array while skipping the heading.